# How to restore database with 2 mdf and 2 ldf files leaving only 1 mdf/ldf pair?

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-backups, database-restore, logfiles

I've got a .bak file (SQL Server 2008) which contains 2 mdf and 2 ldf files.

When I try to restore a database from it, it creates all 4 of those files.

I've never seen this before, and was wondering how do I go to the good-old 1 file pair system (1 mdf/1 ldf)?

Any insight on 2 file pairs being in the backup will help as well.

p.s.: my setup does not have any Ndf files, both are Mdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to move the data from the secondary mdf(isn't it ndf?) into the first. This all assumes you've done the restore.

Let's say your 2 files are `m1` and `m2`.

Use [`DBCC SHRINKFILE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx) to move and empty your ndf.

```
--move all data out of this file
DBCC SHRINKFILE ('m2', EMPTYFILE )
```

You likely will have to restart [SQL Server in single user mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236.aspx). ([source](http://www.sqlteam.com/Forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=54566))

```
--if trying to delete LDF file, do a Transaction log backup of your DB now

--remove this file from the 
ALTER DATABASE DB_NAME_HERE_NO_QUOTES REMOVE FILE m2
```

Comment: had to do this twice (1 for mdf and 1 for ldf) and it worked. also, Transation log backup is necessary before shrinking and removing the log file.

Answer (score 1):

Using multiple files in a database helps distribute the database over multiple disk drives.

You can't change the number of files when restoring the database, but you can indicate where the files are restored.  Check out the [RESTORE DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) command, MOVE options.

After the database restore you can remove database files.  You have to shrink the file with the option to [empty file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189493.aspx).  Then, you can drop the file with the [ALTER DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522469.aspx) command.